# How to export socket.io instance to other TS modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

I'm trying to export an io object gotten from initializing socket.io to my router module in typescript, do i export io object from server.ts module or initialize socket.io in my router module ? Or any other advised way ?

I tried

> Server.ts

```
export const io = socketIO.listen(server);
```

> customer-router.ts

```
console.log(io)
```

evaluates to undefined.

> Server.ts

```js
import {Server, createServer} from 'http';
// Init express
const app = express();

// Setup socket.io
const server: Server = createServer(app);
export const io = socketIO.listen(server);

export default server;
```

> Start.ts

```
import { logger } from '@shared';
// Start the server
const port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000);
server.listen(port, () => {
    logger.info('Express server started on port: ' + port);
});
```

> BaseRouter.ts

```
import CustomerRouter from './customers/Customers';

const router = Router();
const path = '/ChowApi';

// Add sub-routes
router.use(CustomerRouter.path, CustomerRouter.router);

// Export the base-router
export default { router, path };
```

> Customer.ts

```
console.log(io)

export default { router, path };
```

I expect output to be io object,
But actual output is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me out with this, So just in-case anyone runs into this.

```
// server.ts

import * as socketIO from 'socket.io';
import BaseRouter from './routes/Base';

const server = createServer(app);
const io = socketIO.listen(server);

const baseRouter = BaseRouter(io);
app.use(baseRouter.path, baseRouter.router)


// BaseRouter.ts

import { Router } from 'express';

export const BaseRouter = (io) => {
  // Init router and path
  const router = Router();
  const path = '/ChowApi';

  // Add sub-routes
  const customerRouter = CustomerRouter(io);
  router.use(customerRouter.path, customerRouter.router);

  return {
    router,
    path
  };
}

export default BaseRouter;

// Customer.ts

const CustomerRouter = (io) => {

  // Init router and path
  const router = Router();
  const path = '/customers';

  return {
    router,
    path
  }
};

export default CustomerRouter;
```

I don't know why I didn't think of this.